# Azure DevOps - User Story showing in the Sprint board but not in the Work Items board

Tags: ado, sprint

I have never seen this. But one of my stories is showing in my Boards>Sprint and in my Boards>Boards but not in the overall Work Items list.

Any idea why?

I tried to filter by the tags, i tried scrolling down by story ID.
Expected to see the User Story show in the main list of Work Items

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.